# h1 refuses to nest in div

Tags: html, css

I have a div. It is 100% width and 150 pixels tall. I nested an `<h1>` tag in it, and it sits under an image instead of next to it.

```
<body>
<div class='topbar'>
<img src='img source is here'/>
<h1>
GO COSMOS!!!
</h1>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 body {
      background-color: #aaffaa;
    }
    .topbar {
      width: 100%;
      height: 150px;
      background-color: #00bb00;
    }
    img {
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
    }
    h1 {

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

A heading (`<h1>`,`<h2>`,etc) is a **block** level element:

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block." This article helps to explain what this means.<sub>[Source: MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)</sub>

Simply display the h1 `inline-block` like:

```
 h1 {
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align:top;
   /*vertical-align aligns it at the top of the image, instead of the baseline*/
 }
```

[JSFiddle Example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/ftuhhe7a/2/)

Answer (score 0):

All header tags are `block` by default, meaning it spans the width 100%. If you want it side-by-side another element you need to change the `display` like so:

```
h1 {
    display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Try to add display inline to img too.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to float the two inside elements left. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/8gy5oprw/1/

```
 img {
   float: left;
   height: 150px;
   width: 150px;
 }

 h1 {
   float: left;
 }
```